# Node Error while installing express framework. Issue might be related to SSL

Tags: node.js

npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kautuk Singh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-22T16_41_13_909Z-debug-0.log

already reinstall node
tried lower version
ran several commands but didnt get any result